# Cannot boot into Ubuntu [Dual-boot]

Tags: dual-boot

Hi I have installed Ubuntu onto my 2nd hard drive. During the Ubuntu installation I chose "something else" and selected the unallocated partition I created specifically for Ubuntu. I did not choose the "install alongside windows 8.1" option because my current windows os is running on my SSD. I want Ubuntu to be installed on my secondary HDD.

I am almost 100% I have it installed correctly. I just cannot figure out for the life of me how I would go about booting into the OS. I do not get any sort of boot manager.
I have looked to add a boot option in my BIOS but there were no options for the installed Ubuntu.

Any sort of tips or feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What brand/model system? Is Windows UEFI and then did you install Ubuntu in UEFI. Maybe best to see details, post link in above post: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

When the Computer starts, after loading the BIOS, it boots from a Operating System Source which can be Hard drive ,USB drive, Ethernet or DVD/Floppy Drive. The order in which these source should be checked if there is any Operating System installed on them or not, can be changed from **Boot Order** in BIOS settings.

If you have two Operating Systems on one Hard Drive and you wish to select which one to use every time you turn on your computer,that's where **Boot Manager** comes into action. Boot Manager identifies all the installed O.S. on the Hard Drive (or some other source like USB, DVD etc. for that matter) and gives the user choice to choose one.

Here, since you have **two Hard Drives** (one SSD and other HDD), you actually have **two sources to boot from** and hence there is no role for Boot Manager. So if you want to choose a particular Hard Drive each time your computer starts, you have select from **Boot Device Options** each time (either by pressing Esc or F12 or something else depending on your computer).

Hope that helps.

Comment: The biggest problem with that is, for some reason there is no other detected OS other than Windows. I know for sure that Ubuntu is installed correctly. Thanks for the reply though! Hope it helps some others!

Comment: @TylerxYMx  Well even after you boot your HDD from **"Boot Device Options"** and found no OS on that, the only reason I see is that you haven't installed Ubuntu correctly.
Make sure when you choose **"Something Else"** and create partitions on HDD, you are actually making partition(s) on HDD (and not SSD) by selecting the correct Hard Drive from the drop down menu at the bottom.